# Oracle SQL Select IF/Then/Case into Column Results

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case

So I have a case statement that I'm trying to figure out, and ultimately I don't think I have to do this as a case, but I tried doing it as a sub-query within the select statement and that did not work.

```
SELECT ID.ID_VALUE AS ID,

(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'TEST' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END) 
    AS TEST_DATE, 
(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'NON-T' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END)
    AS NON-T_DATE
```

When I processes this, I end up with a result that contains 3 columns and 2 rows. The one row contains a TEST_DATE value in one column, and nothing in another. Then in the other row I have a value in NON-T_DATE and nothing in another cell. The ID values are the same so I don't know why I can't get the results in the same row without duplicates.

Here's an example of my results:

```
     || ID  ||  TEST_DATE  ||  NON-T_DATE  ||
     || 10  ||  1/1/2015   ||     NULL     || 
     || 10  ||    NULL     ||   1/2/2015   ||
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and aggregation functions:

```
SELECT ID.ID_VALUE AS ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'TEST' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END) AS TEST_DATE, 
       MAX (CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'NON-T' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END) AS NON-T_DATE 
FROM . . .
GROUP BY ID.ID_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a separate Case statement. The only way you could get them in one shot, is to run another pass, where that result set is a derived table, and print that out.

```
select ID_VALUE, TEST_DATE, NON-T_DATE   from
(SELECT ID.ID_VALUE AS ID,

(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'TEST' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END) 
    AS TEST_DATE, 
(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'NON-T' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END)
    AS NON-T_DATE ) derivedtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write your query as mentioned below

```
SELECT ID.ID_VALUE AS ID,
(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'TEST' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'NON-T' THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') END)
    AS NON-T_DATE 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you either want to `pivot` the data or use the old `max(case` approach

```
SELECT ID.ID_VALUE AS ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'TEST' 
                THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY')
                ELSE NULL
            END) AS TEST_DATE, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN OBJ.STATUSCD = 'NON-T' 
                THEN TO_CHAR(OBJ.DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                ELSE NULL
            END) AS NON-T_DATE 
  FROM <<something>>
 GROUP BY id.id_value
```

The additional `ELSE` clauses aren't strictly needed.  But I'd rather be explicit rather than hoping that the next person to read this code remembers that a `CASE` statement returns `NULL` if there are no matches and `MAX` will pick the non-NULL value from a set.